# Why is a relative clause not always an appositive?

Tags: relative-clauses, appositives

A relative clause adds information: I, who am red, am here.

Non-restrictive appositions have phrases injected into a sentence: I, red giant, am here. The injections add no essential information.

Then why is the relative clause in "My sister, whose name is Alice Smith, likes roses." not an appositive? Doesn't it have the same meaning as "Alice Smith" in  "My sister, Alice Smith, likes roses"? Why is it not usable as an appositive?

Update:

Could it be that a relative clause can be part of a noun phrase that is an appositive, but not be an appositive itself?

Comment: I think an appositive is always a noun phrase. You can replace the noun that it's referring to with the appositive and it's still grammatical, e.g. *Alice smith likes roses*. You can't do that with a relative clause: *Whose name is Alice Smith likes roses.* You'd have to expand it to *The person whose name is Alice Smith likes roses.*

Comment: That's a great example, and helps a lot to clear the confusion.

Comment: @Barmar Many people extend the idea of apposition to constituents besides NPs. For example: "My sister hates--absolutely loathes--spinach." But in any case, it's certainly not a relative clause, as you say.

Comment: @MarcInManhattan Good point, but the apposition is still the same part as the phrase it apposes. So if you appose a verb, it's a verb phrase. And the substitution principle still applies: *My sister absolutely loathes spinach*

Comment: @Barmar Yes, I agree.

Comment: Non-restrictive relative clauses are effectively the same pragmatically as appositives -- they're separate utterances with some relevance, shoehorned into one sentence frame. _My son the doctor_ could be viewed as a reduced version of _my son, who is/was a doctor_, the same way _the man on the corner_ can be viewed as a reduced version of _the man who is/was on the corner_.

Comment: @MarcInManhattan We need 'standard' definitions. In the case of appositives it's _dependents which when substituted for the matrix NP in a declarative clause systematically yield a clause which is an entailment of the original_. Note that an appositive is an NP functioning as a modifier in NP structure or as a supplement.

Comment: Thanks for the downvotes, guys.

Comment: @BillJ I agree that it would be better if everyone defined terms the same way.

Comment: They tried that before and it didn't work.

Comment: @JohnLawler That was when God split us up into many nations with different languages, right?

Answer (score 0):

There is a long history of the word '*apposition*'.  The word is, as so often, derived from Latin.  The verb *pono* means *I place* or *I put*.  The preposition *ad* means *towards* or *close to*.  Put the final *d* of *ad* next to the initial *p* of *pono* and it fades from *a**dp**ono* into the double *p* of ***app**ono*.  (Try saying 'adpono' quickly over and over again and you'll see.)  The noun *apposition* is formed from the supine *appositum* (making the noun *appositio* - so our friend *apposition* and its related adjectival form, *appositive*.  In the same way we have *oppose* (from ***ob**pono* (I place **in the way** of) and *opposition*.

In a sense, your question is a reasonable one.  In the sentence "I, the red person, am here.", the question "what is the noun phrase *the red person* doing in the sentence?" is, indeed, that it is a noun phrase **in apposition to** the subject *I*.

So why should we not say that the corresponding **relative clause** "who am red" is also *in apposition* to the subject *I*?  It is because **no special explanation is needed** to explain the relationship of a relative clause to some noun or noun phrase in the sentence.  Relative clauses exist to be *related* to some noun or noun phrase in the sentence.  Thw relationship is built in. So they do not need any special explanation.

So, in a sense, you could say that a relative clause or, at least, its relative pronoun is in a sense *appositive*.  It makes sense.  But it is not conventional to say that.  So in a test or examination, stick to what the teacher or text book tells you.

Here is what Greenbaum says at 3.28 of *The Oxford English Grammar*

> Apposition is similar to co-ordination in that it links items of similar grammatical status.  The difference is between them is that the appositives are identical in their reference (refer to the same person or the same thing) or they overlap in their reference (one appositive included in the reference of the other).  **Typically**  the units in apposition are noun phrases.

He gives some examples, none of which directly involves a relative clause, which is dealt with separately at length.`

Comment: There are conflicting definitions, with as usual some claiming that only their usage is the correct one, for 'appositive'. I've seen _They osculated (kissed)_ given as containing an example of an appositive. Though a more common synonym is given in explanation, both _They osculated_ and _They kissed_ are grammatical and have the same meaning.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth:  I don't think we disagree.  Ironically, of course, the precedence of usage over 'rules' applies even to syntax/grammar.  My point is that "Y is in apposition to X" is (at least in its origin) an answer to the question "What is Y doing in the sentence?", in a context where it is not obviously the subject or object of some verb.  A relative or a demonstrative pronoun can even be in apposition to a sentence.  Which I am exemplifying as I type.

Comment: I'm never quite sure who to agree with. Well, that's hyperbole.